# Tkinter AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make a factor finder tinker application based on my previous cml based factor finder.
But whenever I use the entry.get function, it gives me this error:

```
entry1.get(root) == uinput
```

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'`

Here is my code:

```
#Factor Finder 1-100
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

#Code Start
  
label1 = Label(root,text="Enter the Number to find factor of: -").pack
entry1 = Entry(root, borderwidth=5).pack
entry1.get(root) == uinput 
for i in range (1,1000):
    if (uinput%i == 0):
        factortext == i
label2 = Label(root, text=factortext).pack
#Code End

root.mainloop()
```

Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where the code says, for example,`Entry(root, borderwidth=5).pack`, what do you expect that to mean? What do you see when you look up `pack` in the documentation? In your own words, why does the code **not** say, for example, `root = Tk`, or `root.mainloop`? Why would that be incorrect? Do you see how the same logic applies for `.pack`?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
entry1 = Entry(root, borderwidth=5).pack
```

To:

```
entry1 = Entry(root, borderwidth=5)
entry1.pack()
```

You are binding `entry1` to an anonymous widget's `pack` method. That's not what you want.

- You need to bind `entry1` to the widget itself.
- Then, invoke the widget's `pack` method.

You'll want to make the same changes for `label1` and `label2`.